# Kendo UI MVVM with TypeScript - Making ViewModels as "classes"

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript

I am transitioning over a project to Typescript, and it uses Kendo UI's MVVM architecture. However I am having a bit of a problem with the concept of classes and its relationship to the view models.

I will establish a class and extend `kendo.data.ObservableObject`, which is what you create a view model from, and populate it with my fields, like this.

```
export class ViewModelSample extends kendo.data.ObservableObject {
   Id: string = null;
   Name: string = null;
   Items: kendo.data.ObservableArray = [];
   // other fields
   constructor() {
      super();
   }

   map(params){
      // some code
   }
}
```

Basically this class represents my view model, nicely encapsulated. So I summon it up like this;

```
var viewModel = new ViewModelSample();
kendo.bind($('#binding-area'), viewModel);
```

This works fairly well, but the behavior becomes kind of awkard. For instance, if I have a collection within the class and I push something to it, the user interface does not update.

If I do this in normal javascript, it works;

```
viewModel.Items.push(new Item(/* parameters */));
// view model updates, and user interface updates
```

however if I do this in typescript, the view model updates, but the DOM does not. I have to manually type in ...

```
viewModel.Items.trigger('change');
```

In order to get the UI to update.

Can anyone help me understand why this would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `items` property as a Kendo ObservableArray. Currently you're only defining its type in TypeScript (I'm surprised the compiler does not complain about this?).

Update your code to:

```
Items: kendo.data.ObservableArray = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);
```

For more information, consult the [Kendo docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observablearray).

Comment: maybe provide a link to some useful documentation, as well.

Comment: This is extremely interesting. Under normal javascript, the `[]` would have automatically been turned into an observable array. But under typescript, it does not? That is fascinating, and also frustrating. Is this behavior by design? or is it a bug in kendo?

Comment: I too am alarmed that the compiler does not complain about it! So far I am ADORING typescript, but it is the little things like this that make me cautious. It isn't that I cannot get around it. I can manually call the updating, but I __should not have to__.

Comment: I'm wondering, are you using a definition file for Kendo? Also, I think you are always required to instantiate it like this, even in plain JavaScript. I added a link to the docs.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the definition file for it. It still did not require that.

Comment: This answer is actually slightly incorrect. Manually making the new `ObservableArray` will not correctly set its `parent` to the ViewModel, which can mess up other MVVM bindings and templates that rely on the parenting chain.

Comment: below is link to a pretty good article discussing this issue.  TL;DR article suggests to instantiate the Items property (as recommended in accepted answer) and then in the constructor to first call super() and then call super.init(this).  Here is link: http://tinyurl.com/k5bgq6u

Answer (score 4):

I had run into this problem too, and it is actually due to the way TypeScript generates the JS.

In normal JS, you can do:

```
new kendo.ObservableObject({
    items: []
});
```

and the constructor will automatically wrap the `items[]` into a new `ObservableArray` for you.

However the behavior fails in TypeScript because the code:

```
export class ViewModelSample extends kendo.data.ObservableObject {
    Items: kendo.data.ObservableArray = [];

    constructor() {
       super();
    }
```

actually generates something like:

```
function ViewModelSample() { // constructor
    _super.call(this);       // call to ObservableObject constructor (super())
    this.Items = [];         // add Items to this.
}
```

So the `Items` property isn't added to the ViewModel until after the `ObservableObject` constructor is called, so Kendo doesn't know about it, and doesn't wrap it into an `ObservableArray`.

The ordering is just backwards from what Kendo expects out of normal JavaScript.

@Anzeo's suggestion to manually init the Items to an `ObservableArray` will mostly work

```
Items: kendo.data.ObservableArray = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);
```

however the ObservableArray's `parent` won't be correctly set to the ViewModel, so sometimes if you try to MVVM bind a function or property on the ViewModel inside a ListView template that is bound to `Items`, it won't be able to find the properties or functions on the ViewModel.

You can prove it by doing this in a devtools console:

```
x = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    items: []
});
x.items.parent(); // returns the object 'x' (correct)

y = new kendo.data.ObservableObject();
y.items = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);
y.items.parent(); // return undefined (but should be the object 'y')
```

This is really a case where TypeScript just gets in the way more than it helps...

---

The correct solution is to do the initial assignment of your class variables *inside* your constructor, before the call to `super()`.

```
class ViewModelSample extends ObservableObject {
    Items: kendo.data.ObservableArray;

    constructor() {
        this.Items = [];
        super();
    }
}
```

which generates the JS in the correct order:

```
function ViewModelSample() {
    this.Items = [];  // Items assigned before call to ObservableObject constructor
    _super.call(this);
}
```

---

Interestingly, the playground on typescriptlang.org doesn't seem to care that the line:

```
this.Items = [];
```

assigns an Array to a variable that is supposed to be of type `ObservableArray`, but if the real compiler throws an error, then you could also just do

```
this.Items = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);
```

and that should work. As long as the generated JS adds the `Items` property to the object before the `ObservableObject` constructor is called.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `super.init(this)` at the end of your constructor to properly set up the dependency tracking. As per the documentation:

```
constructor() {
    ...

    super();
    super.init(this);
}
```