# Typescript with Kendo MVVM - To declare as Observable or Not?

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript

Using `Kendo MVVM` with `Typescript` has been mostly pleasant, but I ran into an issue before and it is rearing its head again... See this question for more details about the original.

#### [Typescript with Kendo MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240818/kendo-ui-mvvm-with-typescript-making-viewmodels-as-classes)

The general problem was that I needed to define the array as a `kendo.data.ObservableArray`. Now here is the issue I am running into ...

I do not understand when I am supposed to declare a property as observable, or just leave it as normal and let the process be natural. In fact I am gravely confused about the entire ordeal. To cite example ...

```
export class Prototype  {
    public Editing: boolean = false;
    public Id: string = "";
    public Name: string = "";
    public Mutations: any[] = [];
    public Tags: any[] = [];
    public Conditions: any[] = [];

    };
}

var viewModel = kendo.observable(new Prototype());
viewModel.Mutations.push({ // new data // });
```

This WORKS. This is REALLY confusing to me, because I did not extend `ObservableObject` as in my original example. If I print out the view model, I can see that all of the arrays were converted to `ObservableArray`, which is exactly what I want.

But then later, I have a similar situation with a more nested part of the program...

```
export class Condition {
    public Label: string = "Pushed Condition";
    public Parts: observableArray = kendo.observableHierarchy([]);

    constructor(data?: any, mapped?: any) {
        for (name in mapped) {
            this[name] = mapped[name];
        }

        for (name in data) {
            this[name] = data[name];
        }
    }

    public onRemove(e) {
        e.data.parent().remove(e);
    }

    public Push(data: any) {
        data.onRemove = e => {
            e.data.parent().remove(e);
        };
        this.Parts.push(data);
    }
}
```

Now then this is where it totally blows my brain out. One of these objects is created as a property on an ObservableArray, but then it does NOT get turned into an observable. So the following ...

```
$mutation.Conditions.push(new Condition());
```

does not behave as observable, and does not update. I have to explicitly do it as ...

```
$mutation.Conditions.push(kendo.observable(new Condition()));
```

But I don't usually have to do this when adding something to the `Mutations[]` collection. I can just go ...

```
viewModel.Mutations.push(new Mutation());
```

and everything is fine.

It gets further confusing with the `Parts` array of Condition. If I declare it as `any[]`, it does not work - even if I create the Condition with `kendo.observable`. The only way I was able to make it work is to explicitly declare it as an `ObservableArray`.

Can anyone help me make sense of this? I have the program working like I want, but I am vastly confused and I find that declaring these differently in different places is really obtuse, and I don't like it. It will make my code much harder to maintain over time.

Comment: In your example, viewModel is of type kendo.observable. What is the type for $mutation ?

Comment: It is just a standard javascript object; Which is part of what confuses me. When I push a standard object onto an `observableArray`, it turns it into an observable - but if I declare it as an actual observable, it doesn't work.

Comment: so $mutation is not created as `kendo.observable(new Prototype());`? any chance you could copy the relevant parts of your code into a sample project we could play with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have actually three questions, I will split up my answer in three parts.

### Part 1

In your first example, you wrap the entire `Prototype` as an observable. Hence, Kendo will make sure all of its properties are observable as well. You confirmed this by printing out the result. This is also mentioned [on the kendo.observableObject docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/observableobject):

> Important: Complex fields are automatically wrapped in nested
>   ObservableObject instances. Array fields are wrapped as
>   kendo.data.ObservableArray objects. The change event of the child
>   objects will bubble to the parent ObservableObject. Fields, which name
>   are prefixed with an underscore will not be wrapped.

### Part 2

In your second example, I cannot tell if `$mutation.Conditions` is an observable array or not? In the latter case, that's the issue. It won't update because you're pushing to a native array, which will not wrap its items as observables. In case it is, I'd need to view the sources of the `mutation` class (assuming you have such a class?).

### Part 3

You assign a `kendo.observableHierarchy` to `Parts`. As such you can't declare `Parts` as `any[]`, because the `kendo.observableHierarchy` is not an array but an object. You could declare `Parts` as `any` but I'm wondering why you wouldn't strongly type your code? What's wrong with declaring it as an `observableArray`?

I hope this demystifies what's happening.

Comment: Slightly. The real problem I am having is figuring out how many levels deep Kendo will convert normal objects to observables if the root model is turned into an observable. The problem is that it does not seem consistent, and that is confusing me.

Comment: From the docs I assume that each time Kendo wraps a complex property in an `ObservableObject` the same rule would be applied again to that object. So I assume it works recursively.

Comment: So there is no harm in having something declared as an observable array already? even if it tries to automatically wrap it again later?

Comment: No, that's no issue. Kendo will notice it is already an observable and hence won't try to wrap it again.

Comment: `Conditions: []` is an observable array because it is a property on `Prototype`, which got wrapped in `kendo.observable` at the start. That is exactly the problem. I cannot tell what the behavior to expect is, either. Declaring them as observable in the code `does.not.work`. It does not produce the desired results; At all. It causes all kinds of extremely awkward behavior with the bindings and is a far cry short of usable in any way.